# objective c and cocos2d allocated object managment

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am wondering on how would i implement the transition between scenes, in the best way.

My app has a `ccscene1` in `class1` ,     and `ccscene2` in `class2`.

when i am making a transition from scene1 to scene2 , there are many allocated instances on scene1 init method, that i dont want to release/allocate each time i live the scene.
I am wondering how can i implement scene1 so that all allocated instances( and some of them are server tcp connects) will not allocated again when back from 2, but only at first launch, and still stay valid during all scenes transitions.

**one solution :**
set a global flag and from the delegate set it to 1 on first launch, than check if this is the first launch on the init method of scene1, and allocate objects.

After i leave scene1, this objects will remain valid when i am back? (lets say i am not releasing them ) ?

The main goal is to not connect to server each transition, and keep the delegate instances at scene1 valid(for case i am using solution1)

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) )

    {
       socketInstance=[[SocketConnector alloc]init]; //only once !
       socketInstance.delegate=self;

     //later on i have transition :

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.7f scene:[AdressBookScene scene]]];
```

I am seeking for the "professional" way to do this .

Comment: A professional way to manage it, is to let another class handle all those allocation stuff. Where you can alloc, get them, and free them of course. A simple basic proxy class will do the trick. But be aware than when you free them, you should make guaranty than the client who use them is notified too.

Comment: The simple answer is, take the object creation that you don't want to change each time you init the scene, out of the scene's init code, and put it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pushScene` to run scene2. That will preserve the scene1 entirely and keep it in memory. You can then continue to `replaceScene` scene2 with other scenes, and eventually call `popScene` to go back to scene1.

Comment: This is also a good answer depending on the situation. You would use this if the running of the second scene is temporary, and if you don't need to free up the memory from scene 1 when running scene 2.

Comment: @LearnCococs2D thanks, but i have read that push scene is not recommanded is it right ? the scene2 is only to pick some image and thats it .